# Accessing values in annotation of a test in a different class - TestNg

Tags: java, testng

I have a custom `Annotation` I created as below

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestConfig {
    String[] value();
}
```

I have test that extends a `BaseClass`.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyTest extends BaseClass {

    @Test
    @TestConfig({ "enableCookies" })
    public void startTest() {
        startInstance();
    }
}
```

Now I need to access the values inside `@TestConfig` annotation inside my `BaseClass` which is below

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

```
public class BaseClass {

    public void startInstance() {
        System.out.println("starting instance");
        //I need to access the value supplied in "MyTest" inside @TestConfig annotation here. How do I do that.
    }

    @BeforeSuite
    public void runChecks() {
        System.out.println("Checks done....");
    }
}
```

I know I can do `TestConfig config = method.getAnnotation(TestConfig.class)` but how do I access the TestNG `TestMethod`class? Please help.

Comment: What do you want to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like (but remove the direct call in the test method):

```
@BeforeMethod
public void startInstance(Method m) {
    System.out.println("starting instance");
    //I need to access the value supplied in "MyTest" inside @TestConfig annotation here. How do I do that.
    TestConfig tc = m.getAnnotation(TestConfig.class);
    System.out.println(tc.value());
}
```